# Xamarin Forms NU1202 & NU1608 Error

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I tried installing xamarin forms in my computer today then tried to make a blank cross platform proj. after I run the proj using xamarin live I get this error:

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start [Android SDK Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=vswin)

[image]

and select the latest Android 8.1 Platform SDK (API 27)

[image]

In the Android Project properties, select "Use latest Platform (Android 8.1)"

[image]

Now restore the NuGet packages and rebuild the app.

Comment: this doesn't matter if you set the Min Version to Lollipop in the Android Manifest tab.